# Angular2 routing using (2.0.0-rc.5) routing

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

For the App i'm trying to build, here's how the rouging paths should be:

[image]

that is from the app.component is my bootstrap class and it hold links to signin and signup pages. Although the dashboard should be in the same level, it should be visible only when the user is signed up. And in the dashboard component, there are two child components, summary and detailed panels.

here's my routing configurations:

```ts
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import {SignInComponent} from "./auth/signin.component";
import {SignUpComponent} from "./auth/signup.component";
import {DashboardComponent} from "./dashboard/dashboard.component";
import {PageNotFoundComponent} from "./error/page-not-found.component";
import {UsageInformationComponent} from "./dashboard/usage-information.component";
import {DetailedInformationComponent} from "./dashboard/detailed-info.component";

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/signin',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
        path: 'signin',
        component: SignInComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'signup',
        component: SignUpComponent,
    },
    {
        path: 'dashboard',
        component: DashboardComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'summary',
        component: UsageInformationComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'detail',
        component: DetailedInformationComponent
    },
    {
        path: '**',
        component: PageNotFoundComponent
    }
];

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

here's the app.module class:

```ts
@NgModule(<NgModuleMetadataType>{
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        routing
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        SignInComponent,
        SignUpComponent,
        DashboardComponent
        UsageInformationComponent,
        DetailedInformationComponent,
        PageNotFoundComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        HeroService,
        AuthService,
        appRoutingProviders
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

but whenever I tried to access the Summary component, always the corresponding path is not found, hence PageNotFoundComponent is fired.
here's the code in dashboard page:

```ts
<div class="container-fluid">
    <header class="row spacing">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a routerLink="/summary" routerLinkActive="active">Summary</a></li>
                        <li><a routerLink="/detail" routerLinkActive="active">Summary</a>Detail</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
</div>
<fr-dashboard *ngIf="hasLogin()"></fr-dashboard>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

To test the routes, I tried to do the following: when the signin button is clicked, page should be redirected to dashboard

signin button:

```ts
<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="performSignIn()">Sign In</button>
```

navigation:

```ts
performSignIn(){
        this._router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
    }
```

But when click action performed, I get the following message in the browser:

[image]

can anyone please let me know what is the issue here. I'm using angular2 version: (2.0.0-rc.5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want `summary` and `detail` to be child routes of `dashboard` you need to define it like child routes:

```ts
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/signin',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
        path: 'signin',
        component: SignInComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'signup',
        component: SignUpComponent,
    },
    {
        path: 'dashboard',
        component: DashboardComponent,
        children: [
            path: '',
            redirectTo: 'summary',
            pathMatch: 'full'
        },
        {
            path: 'summary',
            component: UsageInformationComponent
        },
        {
            path: 'detail',
            component: DetailedInformationComponent
        },
        ]
    },
    {
        path: '**',
        component: PageNotFoundComponent
    }
];
```

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have misspelled "Component" as "Comonent". This could be the source of your problem.

This appears here:

```
{
    path: 'summary',
    component: UsageInformationComonent
},
{
    path: 'detail',
    component: DetailedInformationComonent
},
```

and here:

```
UsageInformationComonent,
DetailedInformationComonent,
```

Comment: But there is another problem.

Comment: But there is another problem.
When the login was successfull, redirecting to the /dashboard was not successful. for example, for testing purposes, I tried to redirect to the dashboard page once the sign in is clicked:

<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="performSignIn()">Sign In</button>

performSignIn(){
        this._router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
}

App routing:

{
 path: 'signin',
 component: SignInComponent
},
{
 path: 'dashboard',
 component: DashboardComponent
},

But i'm getting the error: {"message":"Not Found","error":{"status":404}}

Comment: Could you post the full error log for that exact test case? That'd help me pinpoint the problem a little better. Also, are you importing all of those components in the routing config file?

Comment: Hi Kevin, I've udpated the main question with more details, with the error message I'm getting. Please note that there's no error shown in the browser console, only a message is displayed.

Comment: Hm, would it be possible to temporarily remove the pagenotfound route so that it's forced to push an error to the browser console?

Comment: I did that too. But I'm not getting any different error. It's the same message.

Comment: I can upload files to someplace and give you the link if you can have a look at it.

Comment: Check out Günter Zöchbauer's answer, I think he has a better understanding of the issue than I do :)

Comment: Seems so. Thanks Kevin :)